# Why does AbstractCollection.toArray() handle the case of changed size?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, concurrency

There's this strange code in `AbstractCollection`:

```
public Object[] toArray() {
    // Estimate size of array; be prepared to see more or fewer elements
    Object[] r = new Object[size()];
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
        if (! it.hasNext()) // fewer elements than expected
            return Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
        r[i] = it.next();
    }
    return it.hasNext() ? finishToArray(r, it) : r;
}
```

The part "be prepared to see more or fewer elements" is IMHO a pure non-sense:

- In case the collection changes in the meantime, the iterator throw a `ConcurrentModification` exception anyway.
- I haven't found any non-concurrent subclass supporting this, especially

  - the `ArrayList` uses `Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size)` which could (due to visibility issues) copy a bunch of `null`s instead of the data in case of resizing,
  - the `LinkedList` throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if you're lucky enough.

Am I overlooking something?

Would you support this feature in your collection (meant for general use)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the JAVA DOC of [toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toArray%28%29)

> This implementation returns an array containing all the elements
>   returned by this collection's iterator, in the same order, stored in
>   consecutive elements of the array, starting with index 0. The length
>   of the returned array is equal to the number of elements returned by
>   the iterator, **even if the size of this collection changes during
>   iteration, as might happen if the collection permits concurrent
>   modification during iteration.The size method is called only as an
>   optimization hint; the correct result is returned even if the iterator
>   returns a different number of elements**.

Comment: Sorry, I'm removing my question as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401644/whats-the-usage-of-the-code-in-the-implementation-of-abstractcollections-toarr?rq=1

Comment: I am not so sure of it. I have not posted a question yet and i don't know how to remove it. Thanks :)

Comment: @maaartinus: see this [post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/42297) for delete answer

Comment: @Aniket: Forget it, nobody complained about a duplicate (and I had't found it before), so what. ;)